# createing Time Ruler block like google io 2012

Tags: android

I want to create time ruler block like Google io 2012.I know it open source library i can use it but i have to create it in very simple manner.So please suggest me and provide some example.I am new in Android Programming. 
Any help will be more appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, Google I/O app is available for download, here you go: [iosched - Google I/O app for Android](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/)

Comment: i want use only time ruler view.i do not want use the whole library.thanks for your reply.